# Unable to start activity. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client not initialized

Tags: android, api, dropbox

I would love some help. I am new using dropbox api, I am using the resources available here:https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java
It is working fine, I can upload files perfectly, but then, when I download a file, you can see that is downloaded but then the app crashes with the following error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client not initialized.

This is my git repository, https://github.com/ghilbing/ProbandoDropbox

If you can help me find the error, I would be really thankful.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/issues/238 ]

Comment: When i click on drobox login button than "This app has reached its user limit" this message appear.
So please reached user limit after i able to test your project and resolve your issue.